# Could nod convert variant of type(OleSter) into type(Currency)

Tags: clipboard, delphi-7

I have a dbgrid, I want to copy two columns in it with "Ctl + C" both columns

[image]

did so but there is a mistake

```
procedure TForm24.mniN2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin  
Clipboard.AsText:=qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent']+'='+qry2.FieldValues['result'];
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Don't perform concatenation of `Variant` values of different types. In this case, you can use `VarToStr()` and then concat the resulting strings. `Clipboard.AsText := VarToStr(qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent']) + '=' + VarToStr(qry2.FieldValues['result']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Remy Lebeau for the answer, your answer is correct, everything works

```
begin
  Clipboard.AsText:=VarToStr(qry2.FieldValues['name_subagent'])+'='+VarToStr(qry2.FieldValues['result']);
end;
```